# Matching double slash but not http:// or https://

Tags: regex

I'm trying to implement syntax highlighting using Regex matching, for single-line comments denoted using `//`. However, there are places in the code where we store URLs (starting with `http://` or `https://`) as strings, and obviously these should not be identified as comments. How can I build a Regex string to correctly match both cases?

Currently, the Regex that I am using to match `//`, while still incorrectly handling URLs, is this:

`[\/][\/]+.*`

My closest attempt to try to exclude URLs is this:

`[^:][\/][\/]+.*`

But this doesn't work perfectly, as it requires that there be some character preceding the `//`. It could be the case that the two slashes are the first two characters on the line, and in this case it doesn't work. Making the `[^:]` optional also doesn't work, as it fixes the aforementioned case but then `http://` or `https://` are once again improperly matched.

Comment: Try `(?<!http:)(?<!https:)\/\/.*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind with a regex like this:

```
(?<!http:)\/\/
```

You can have something like this for both protocols

```
(?<!http:|https:)\/\/
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/FoN6e8/1)**

Comment: `(?<!:)\/\/` distilling it to the basic answer reduces the search time by almost half.